# Quarkus with GraalVM got problem for building native image

Tags: javascript, native, quarkus

```
<!--javascript运行环境-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
      <version>23.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
      <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
      <version>23.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello1() {
        try (Context context = Context.create()) {
            Value jsResult = context.eval("js", "function add(a, b) { return a + b; }; add(5, 3);");
            return "Result from JS: " + jsResult.asInt();
        }
    }
```

```bash
mvn package -Dnative
```

```
Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 1
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:468)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:258)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

so, I can not use javascript in native image mode? do I have some altive solution?

Comment: I find a solution from github: https://github.com/alukin/polyglot-test-quarkus. It works well with GraalVM Community Edition 22.3.3, which is jdk17. but It's memory is higher than jdk21. so, the feature is not ready for latest graalvm now?